# localhost redirected you too many times. in codeigniter hooks

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, hook, codeigniter-3

I;m working on a codeigniter project. I want to create a hook so that, it verify the user login every time when he load the class.
my Hook

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
        'class'    => 'Auth_login',
        'function' => 'is_logged_in',
        'filename' => 'Auth_login.php',
        'filepath' => 'hooks',
);
```

and also enabled in the config file.

```
/**
* Auth_login
*/
class Auth_login
{
    /**
     * loading the CI instance
     * @var [object]
     */
    private $CI;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->library('session');
        $this->CI->load->helper('url');
    }

    /**
     * Check the enduser for login verify, every time when the enduser
     * loads the controller.
     */
    public function is_logged_in() 
    {
        /**
        *  if end user is not logged in, redirect to the login page
        */  
        if(!$this->CI->session->userdata('is_logged_in')) 
        {
            $this->CI->session->set_tempdata('faliure','Please sign in to continue');
            redirect(site_url('login/index'));
        }
    }
}
```

It checks for the session login verify for the end user. If user not logged in then redirect to the login page.
Here is my Controller where it redirects

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {
    // class constructor
    //    public function __construct() {
    //     parent::__construct();
    //         // load default 
    //     $this->load->model('login_model');
    // }

    /**
     * [display the login page, and verify the login page using "form_validation" for server side validation]
     * @return [redirect] [description]
     */
    public function index() 
    {
        $this->load->model('login_model');
        // on form sumbit
        $on_sumbit = $this->input->post('verify');
        if(isset($on_sumbit)) 
        {
            // server side validation for login
           if ($this->form_validation->run('login/login_verify') == FALSE)
            {
                $this->load->view('login');
            }
            else 
            {
                // get the form post value
                $user_name = $this->input->post('user_name');
                $password = $this->input->post('password');
                // verify login
                $verified = $this->login_model->login_verify($user_name,$password);
                if($verified)  // success
                {
                    redirect('dashboard');
                }
                else // failure
                {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('login_failure','Please check your email and password and try again');
                    redirect('login/index');
                }
            }
        }
        // login page
        $this->load->view('login');
    }

    // delete active session
    public function logout() 
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('login');
    }
}
```

When it redirect to the login controller, it show errors like
since it working on the local system
"**localhost redirected you too many times**"
what is the actual problem with this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can u try something like this sample
**redirect('/index.php/it_inventory/get_users', 'refresh');**

Comment: Above i have added 'refresh' as second argument .. add this in all your redirects for now in which you are having this issue.

Comment: i tried that too,it refreshes the page recursively. it doesn't load the page.. any other solution.. PLEASE

Answer (score 0):

You want to check if you are not on login controller or in other words you want to have hook functionality on every controller except login where you redirect if condition not met. You can exclude that controller in condition this way:

```
/**
* Auth_login
*/
class Auth_login
{
    /**
     * loading the CI instance
     * @var [object]
     */
    private $CI;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->library('session');//working with sessions - you want sessions 
        //to be loaded ASAP so better way would be having it in 
        //APPPATH.'config/autoload.php' instead in all classes

        /** 
         * @tutorial how to exclude hook interaction with particular class/controller
         */
        if ( strtolower( $this->CI->router->class ) == 'login' )
        {
            return;
        }

        $this->CI->load->helper('url');
    }

    /**
     * Check the enduser for login verify, every time when the enduser
     * loads the controller.
     */
    public function is_logged_in() 
    {
        /**
        *  if end user is not logged in, redirect to the login page
        */  
        if(!$this->CI->session->userdata('is_logged_in')) 
        {
            $this->CI->session->set_tempdata('faliure','Please sign in to continue');
            redirect(site_url('login/index'));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete all sessions from \application\cache\session